# How do I track my investment value when using Dollar Cost Averaging strategy

Tags: chart, dollar-cost-averaging

I am in the process of investing a windfall using Dollar Cost Averaging strategy.

I want to plot my portfolio value in a spreadsheet, but if I simply chart the current price, it doesn't reflect the fact that I bought at different prices and that some units might be ahead on the purchase price and some currently behind.

Is there a formula or method that takes the range of purchase prices into account when calculating current position?

Comment: Why not just take the ending portfolio value divided by the windfall amount? Why does it matter that some lots are ahead and some behind?

Comment: You can do lot-based accounting, or you can do total position based accounting, it really depends on you. Although lot-based accounting does give you more data points and more flexibility.

Comment: @DStanley I am not sure if it _really_ matters, as such, but I am curious to see how the DCA strategy works comparing lots Vs had I invested a lump sum.  It is all about learning for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Tracking DCA investments is no different than tracking 401(k) investments.)

The easy way (which works only if you invest the **same amount** every period, on about the **same day** every period) is to use Excel's =FV() function.

The more flexible method (if you *don't* contribute the same amount every period, at the same time every period) is to compute the series of future values yourself.

The way I do it (and the results match my plan provider's numbers) is with a spreadsheet having one row per purchase, plus three "separate" cells.

In three separate cells, put:

1. the Starting Balance (might be $0),
2. the *Current* Account Balance, and
3. the hypothetical growth rate (which you adjust; start with a reasonable guess, you'll be changing it later).

The columns would be something like this:

```
Date  ESP  Purchase_Price    FV
```

Where:

- `Date` is the day you purchased it.
- `ESP` is "Elapsed Time Since Purchase": how many years from `Date` to Now.  Use the =DATEIF() function, and divide by 365.
- `Purchase_Price` is what it says on the tin: how much money you spent purchasing the investments that period, and
- `FV` (Future Value) is how much that money "should be" worth given the growth rate specified in "Cell 3" above.

Sum up the `FV` column at the bottom of that column.

Compare that `FV` sum to the Current Account Balance.  Adjust the hypothetical growth rate (Cell 3" until the sum of the FV values matches the Current Account Balance, *et voilà* now you know your investment's growth rate.

Comment: Thanks, very useful.  Let's see what else is offered before I accept ;o)